# insert sql statement into mysql database like common string?

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a logger function and it inserts "insert and update queries" to database. altough I apply "mysql_real_escape_string" to the sql stament, I cannot insert it to the database. 
any suggestion please?

Comment: What is the exact error you get and the code you use?

Comment: If you expect people to invest their time answering your question, YOU should invest some time in asking the question. what's the error for starters?

Comment: error message is very common: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`UPDATE faal_ekonkod SET bedel = 12000 WHERE id = 1`)' at line 1"

Comment: In my function, firstly I am controlling stripslashes($value) and mysql_real_escape_string($value) then sending into query string.

my sql query becomes like this:
INSERT INTO kayit (ip, user_id, query) VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 1 `UPDATE faal_ekonkod SET bedel = 12000 WHERE id = 1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO kayit (ip, user_id, query) VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 1 UPDATE faal_ekonkod SET bedel = 12000 WHERE id = 1)
```

In SQL, strings must be quoted. You are also missing a comma. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO kayit (ip, user_id, query) VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 1, 'UPDATE faal_ekonkod SET bedel = 12000 WHERE id = 1')
```

Answer (score 0):

i have also problems with this function, then i use the addslashes() function, its not an answer but a solution.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

Comment: I cannot really get what your answer is about. You mention problems with `mysql_real_escape_string()` you don't give any clue about, you mention `addslashes()` as escape function for MySQL, which is not, and you finally post what appears to be perfectly valid PHP code. Are you suggesting to use it or to avoid it?